# Azure Python SDK Error

Tags: python, api, azure

I have written python code to get azure resources for a subscription using azure-python sdk,
the function to list all the resources inside a resource group is not working, this was working fine a week before, may be the microsoft have changed their api??
I am getting an attribute error,
AttributeError: 'ResourceGroupsOperations' object has no attribute 'list_resources'

Please Find the code below,

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials  
from azure.mgmt.resource.resources import ResourceManagementClient   
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
subscription_id = ''
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
client_id = '',
secret = '',
tenant = '',
)
resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials,subscription_id)
resource_client.providers.register('Microsoft.Batch')
def get_resources():
for rg in resource_client.resource_groups.list():
for item in resource_client.resource_groups.list_resources(rg.name):
print "%s,%s,%s,%s,"%(item.name,item.type,item.location,rg.name)
get_resources()
```

Plz do help on this! thanks in advance !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just an summary , you can find a description of the `list_resources` method has been removed in **2017-05-04** from [SDK source code version statement](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/89182134e29ed34b19edc10a88a074ca8443f17f/azure-mgmt-resource/HISTORY.rst).

```
resource_groups.list_resources has been moved to resources.list_by_resource_group
```

Python SDK upgrade should be the reason for your issue.

Please modify your code as below and it will work.

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials  
from azure.mgmt.resource.resources import ResourceManagementClient   
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
subscription_id = ''
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
client_id = '',
secret = '',
tenant = '',
)
resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials,subscription_id)
resource_client.providers.register('Microsoft.Batch')
def get_resources():
  for rg in resource_client.resource_groups.list():
    for item in resource_client.resources.list_by_resource_group(rg.name):
      print "%s,%s,%s,%s,"%(item.name,item.type,item.location,rg.name)
get_resources()
```

Comment: @user2795938 It's all right .You could mark the answer for others' reference on the forum.Have a nice day !

Comment: Done! Have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because there is no such operation, you are looking for `list_by_resource_group` operation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/python/api/azure.mgmt.resource.resources.v2017_05_10.operations.resourcesoperations?view=azure-python#azure_mgmt_resource_resources_v2017_05_10_operations_ResourcesOperations_list_by_resource_group